# How to know what item is selected?

Tags: reactjs, office365

In microsoft office 365 fabric react exist [DetailsList component](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/detailslist). according to examples it's possible to know how many items were selected. In constructor there is:

```
this._selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() })
    });
```

and this component has next method:

```
private _getSelectionDetails(): string {
    let selectionCount = this._selection.getSelectedCount();

    switch (selectionCount) {
      case 0:
        return 'No items selected';
      case 1:
        return '1 item selected: ' + (this._selection.getSelection()[0] as any).name;
      default:
        return `${selectionCount} items selected`;
    }
  }
```

But how to know what item was selected?I didn't find something like onItemClick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note of this : `(this._selection.getSelection()[0] as any).name;`. So, to get selected item you can: `this._selection.getSelection()`, it should return an array of selected items.